# How can I add an image on EditText

Tags: android, image, android-edittext

I want to dynamically  add image in `EditText`. Is it possible?

if anyone knows please give sample code for that.

Comment: Define "add image in `EditText`"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If something like this:

[image: EditCheck]

is what you're talking about, then you just need to either set the `Drawable{Right | Left | Top | Bottom}` property in the xml, or call the corresponding java command.

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box), null);
```

Comment: java  java command should call setBounds(Rect),or it canot appear image

Comment: You have used the images show in drawable, But i need to show the images throw gallery images if there is any possible to pick the images from the gallery into edit text view.

Comment: Just get the image and put it in a BitmapDrawable.

Comment: ok that and all i did but the images are not showing in edit text field.

Comment: Did you invalidate it after?

Comment: Use `ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.check_box)` instead of `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box)`

Answer (score 60):

[image]

Using the frame layout it is very easy to overcome this.Here another advantage is that you can give click events for buttons.if you set icons using setCompoundDrawables, you cant give the click events.I have implemented in my project that search bar has  delete and search icons.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_magnify" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_remove" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: How can i add click events to button?

Comment: findViewById(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
  });

Comment: can you provide the drawable images!!

Comment: use 
`android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"`
 and remove `singleLine` from `EditText`

Answer (score 53):

using `android:drawableRight` or `android:drawableLeft`
(depend where you prefer align image)

```
<EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/searchedTxt"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        />
```

Comment: This guy deserves a medal. Thanks dude!

Comment: In latest android studio 2.2.3, it is advice to use android:drawableEnd instead of android:drawableRight

Answer (score 28):

you can also try this

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc\n");
    Drawable d = img.getDrawable();
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    editT.setText(ss);
```

Comment: +1 this code is helpful if you want to add more then one drawable to the edit text dynamically. for e.g chating input edittext. User can select smiley icons. one needs to append this Spanable String to the editable.

Comment: where does `3` parameter in `setSpan` come from?

Comment: it's the length on string "abc"

Comment: Hi, in my case it is look like this [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-d7AyAECAIsZGFka0lONWphY2M/edit?usp=docslist_api). Any idea why? I download drawable like this: `thiss.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.friends)`

Answer (score 16):

[image: Test Image]

You can use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

```
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTest);
    text.setText("Test");
    text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null,
                       getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable, null), null);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add an image to your `EditText` through `android:background="@drawable/img"`.

If you want to modify the style by using nine patch or else, but if you want to add a small image in the left of your `EditText` consider using `android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"`.

Answer (score 3):

> extend the edittext class and do code as u want it to be

```
public void setImage(String imageResource) {
    int position = Selection.getSelectionStart(MyEditText.this
            .getText());

    Spanned e = Html.fromHtml("<img src=\"" + imageResource + "\">",
            imageGetter, null);

    MyEditText.this.getText().insert(position, e);
}
```

Comment: what will be the imageResource? Will it be the imagepath like /sdcard/images/image1.jpg?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.pic_name, 0);
```

as suggested here:
[Calling setCompoundDrawables() doesn't display the Compound Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590838/calling-setcompounddrawables-doesnt-display-the-compound-drawable)

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of the `EditText`

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
```

Then create a drawable instance of the image

```
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_warning); // API 21 and below.
```

OR

```
Drawable image = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_warning); // API 22 and above.
```

Then set the image by calling `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom);`

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, image, null);
```

The above line will set the image in the right side of the `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this if you are in adapter class**

```
    holder.myEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null,
            _context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher),
            null);
```

and 
**You can try this if you are in activity class**

```
    myEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null,
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher),
            null);
```