# emoticons in message on Android

Tags: android, web-services, image

I am developing a chat application(like Simple Gtalk) for android mobiles. I am facing few issues in display emoji's/emoticons.

I need to replace the special character to a emojis image. How can i do this?

1. I select Image from grid.
2. Display corresponding special character of image selected into Edit Text along with message i typed.
3. When i click on send button i need to display emojis/ emotions instead of special character in the above list view where i display all the messages i receive from .NET web service. These images(emojis) are stored in drawable folder.

   - I get these messages from web service. But I want to know how can I find and replace the special character with a emojis image along with my text message coming from web service.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to replace the special character to a emojis image

You can refer to [Emoji Picker](http://code.google.com/p/ts-love-android-dev/).

> Display corresponding special character of image selected into Edit Text along with message i typed.

This has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703283/how-can-i-add-an-image-on-edittext/3704545#3704545) on SO

> But i want to know how can i find and replace the special character with a emojis image along with my text message coming from web service.

Check the [Unicode chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf).