# Is this possible to set Image instead of text in Android

Tags: android

I want to set image instead of edit-text view in Android.

Comment: are you set the image left are right in the edittext?

Comment: what's your code ? what have you tried ? why are you unable to do it ? it's just a matter of removing the edit-text and adding an image so it's difficult to see what's the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703283/how-can-i-add-an-image-on-edittext

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create your own TextView with an OnTextChangedListener. In the listener take the last character entered and append it to a cached value. Then replace the value with your own character. (any ASCII character)

If you want to get an image inside then you'd have to take the concept much further and create your own TextView class that probably overrides `onDraw` and adds an image instead of text.