# How do I put images in a EditText field?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'd like to put an image in an EditText field, as shown. How should one go about this? Layered-list with the image on one layer and a lot of padding on the left side of the EditText on the other layer?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703283/how-can-i-add-an-image-on-edittext

Comment: That link solves the problem is Java. The answer deserves merit because it solves in XML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set the image in editText.

```
<EditText
   ......  
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image" />
```

You can set it Left, Right, Top, Bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the

```
setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
```

or

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
```

methods.

Cheers