# What is the best way to send smiley on xmpp android

Tags: android, xmpp

I am little bit confuse for how can i access smiley. I have a Unicode characters of smiley and images that is stored in drawable folder. I know that this is silly question but i am not getting actually what i do for this. So what I use Unicode character or image to send on xmpp server. which one is good. Because i also need to set in edittext. I used ImageGetter to set smiley image in Edittext.

Give your suggestions.

Comment: my suggestion would be to use base64.encode on smiley image then send to destination and base64.decode at the destination.

Answer (score 0):

On the sending side, most XMPP clients just use text renderings of the emoticons, such as:

```
:)
```

On the receiving side, many XMPP clients use a regular expression to find all of the emoticons that they support, and replace them either with a Unicode [Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) (if they know that they have a font that will render the desired character) or a locally-stored bitmap.  If you want to insert an image on Android, I think your question is a dup of [How can I add an image on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703283/how-can-i-add-an-image-on-edittext/5010779#5010779).