# How Can I scale the image on Edit Text

Tags: android, xml

I want to dynamically add an image in EditText. I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703283/how-can-i-add-an-image-on-edittext) to do that and I have succeeded. but, the thing is I cannot scale this image to the size of my text field. It is smaller than my text field.

Here is my text field.

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_passcode"
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="1000dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textPassword">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
```

It displays like this.

[image]

How can I scale this image?

Comment: did you try to set it as your Edit Text Background?

Comment: Do you have any image that can illustrate what you want exactly

Comment: @Manu if you want to show image on center of an edittext you need to use 9 path images or else if you want to show images on left ,right,top and bottom side of a view.Use drawableleft attribute.

Comment: Yes  Chairizky I did set it as Edit Text Background

Comment: Narendra Kothamire ,  my background image shows in white.

Comment: @Manu if you are setting normal image as background.You will get a stretch image.

Comment: Yeah Vishwa I used a p path image.

Comment: @Manu then maybe the problem is in your 9 patch image.In 9 patch the extraction part of an image will be in solid color.i think you did it over on  text.

Comment: Yeah thats a text image. So, what should I do?

Comment: Try set solid color as background...and set your text (which is on image) as a hint on `EditText`...

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@Manu** : 
[Nine Patch:](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) an extension to the `PNG` format allows it to specify information about how to stretch it and place things inside of it.
so i think its your 9 patch image problem .

[Here is downloadable](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) one which is good, it has a simple but clever default image.Try this way.

I hope it will helps you .

Comment: Thanks. Got the answer.