# how to get an image from gallery or take from camera and insert it into an edittext?

Tags: android, image, camera, android-edittext

I'm new to Android programming.
What I'm trying to do is get a image from the gallery or take it from the camera, and insert into the edittext which might have texts on it. (e.g., text....text...text.. [IMAGE])

How should the code for getting a image and insert it into the selected cursor point of the edittext?

Comment: Yu can only set the path of the image in edittext.. Not the image

Comment: I have done this before, many years ago.

I was working on a message app. what I done is adding smileys in the EditText, those smiley icons was images.

Comment: But I saw an application which allows this type of actions. https://youtu.be/_nm06Z3mLJQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to do programmatically:

```
EditText et_EditImage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_EditImage);
et_EditImage.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick), null);
```

Try this to do it in XML file:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_magnify" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_remove" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

I found that on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703283/how-can-i-add-an-image-on-edittext)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried many of the solutions and they all worked!

Comment: I'm glad to listen that. @YoungJunChoi accept the question so that in the future another users can solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with 2 methods

1)With `SpannableString`

```
 SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc\n");
    Drawable d = img.getDrawable();
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    editText.setText(ss);
```

2) With `CompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.image, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It helped me a lots!