# How to set textview side by side of image view

Tags: android, layout, android-imageview, textview

[image: ** How to achieve this view? I can able to show text on right side. how to show it right side and below image view.**]

**How to achieve this view? I can able to show text on right side. How to show it on right side and below image view? It is TextView contains description. So, text can be of one line or 10 lines.

Please Help!!!**

Comment: Yes here both text view and image view are used.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Hello" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No i dont want to use 2 textview. I need to do it by one textview. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
editText.setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image), null, null, null);
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703283/how-can-i-add-an-image-on-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

WebView would be best for this.. Add image view in web and text filling the webview